# Automatically Sync Local Github Repository with Directory on Server

Tags: node.js, git, bash, github, server

I have been attempting to use hooks to automatically pull the updated repo from github to my remote web server. This is the code on the post-receive hook:

```
cd /home/[my username]/document_root/[github repo name]/
git pull origin master
```

I expect this to run when there is a new commit from my development machine that syncs with the one on github, but it doesn't update the files inside of that repo directory. Any help is appreciated, but I am new to using git and github in general.

EDIT: I tried to follow this tutorial but it still doesn't work.
http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

Comment: so you have a repo (local) that push to both github and your remote server? You write `post-receive` hook on the git remote server and it will be triggered when you push. You need to push to both github and your own server (for that to trigger); not just github.

Comment: I have my local repo on my personal computer and then I have a repo on my production server. I am attempting to get them to sync with what I commit from my local machine if that makes sense. @TuanAnhTran

Answer (score 0):

You can push `git post-hook` to Github. Instead, you can use Github's [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)

Comment: I am using a hook on my production server but it is not getting activated when I push from my local machine.

Comment: I attempted to follow this tutorial and it still is not working. This tutorial is what i want to do. http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

Answer (score 0):

you can customize a schedule with crontab. 
for example,  crontab -e  , and input
5 * * * snyc_git.sh

Then it will snyc your respository.